# How do I convert a CVS repository to Mercurial on Windows?

Tags: mercurial, converters, cvs

I can access the CVS server which is authenticated with :pserver:, I managed to checkout from CVS, now I want to try to convert this to Mercurial, with history from CVS.

So, I tried hg convert location-of-CVS-repo

I get the following:

```
assuming destination repo-hg
initializing destination repo-hg repository
connecting to :pserver:username@node:/repo
abort: CVS pserver authentication failed
```

The problem is, how do I set the password?

I found an article about CVSNT and the .cvspass file, which I copied my password from the Windows registry to this file. Trouble is, I don't know the exact format of this file, so what I have is:

```
:pserver:user@node:/repo xyz x123
```

The xyz x123 looks like the password stored in the registry (except, obviously I've changed it). There is a space in that password, so how do I set it in the .cvspass file?

The .cvspass file is in \Users\username on my Windows system.

Comment: I've gotten much further by trying on Linux but still get errors from hg convert. I'm trying to get a copy of the repository - tried cvssuck but that died before completion and left an incomplete directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use Linux with cvs2hg python script and a copy of the repository.